# Finding rank of BA given rank of AB

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I am trying to solve the following linear algebra problem:

> Let $A$ be a $3\times2$ matrix and $B$ be a $2\times3$ matrix such
>   that:
>
> $$ AB = \begin{bmatrix}-2 & -14 & 14 \\ 5 & 15 &-10 \\ 4 & 8 &
> -3\end{bmatrix}. $$
>
> The following facts are known (and easily verified):
>
> 1. $ \mathrm{rank}(AB) = 2 $
> 2. $(AB)^2 = 5AB $
>
> Find the rank of $BA$.

The following is the suggested answer:

$$
\mathrm{rank}(BA) \ge \mathrm{rank}(A(BA)B) = \mathrm{rank}((AB)^2) = 2
$$
$$
\text{Since } BA \text{ is } 2 \times 2, \mathrm{rank}(BA) = 2  
$$

I cannot seem to understand why the following statement holds true:

$$
\mathrm{rank}(BA) \ge \mathrm{rank}(A(BA)B).
$$

From what I know:

$$
\mathrm{rank}(A) \le \min(m,n) \text{ where $A$ is an } m \times n \text{ matrix }
$$
$$
\mathrm{rank}(AB) \le \min(\mathrm{rank}(A),\mathrm{rank}(B)).
$$

I cannot see how to relate these to the above mentioned statement. Could someone please enlighten me?

Comment: see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2007728/finding-matrix-ba-given-ab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$
\operatorname{rank}(A(BA)B) \leq 
\min\{\operatorname{rank}(A),\operatorname{rank}((BA)B)\} \leq 
\operatorname{rank}((BA)B) \leq\\
\min\{\operatorname{rank}(BA), \operatorname{rank}(B)\} \leq \operatorname{rank}(BA)
$$

Comment: +1! That was an extremely astute observation. Thank you!